# In OpenLDAP (Slapd), how do I give users permission to search which groups they're a member of?

Tags: openldap, user-permissions, ldap-query, phpldapadmin, slapd

Currently, only my *admin* user is allowed to search what group a particular user is in.

If I have the following user:

```
dn: uid=tester,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
cn: tester
displayName: tester
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
sn: tester
uid: tester
```

And if the following group has the above user as a member (check its *member* attribute):

```
dn: ou=testingGroup,dc=example,dc=com
cn: testingGroup
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
ou: testingGroup
member: uid=tester,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
```

Then, with the admin credentials, I can do this search successfully:

```
ldapsearch \
    -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" \
    -w ${ADMIN_PW} \
    -b 'dc=example,dc=com' \
    "(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=uid=tester,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com))"
```

I can also successfully do a similar search as the admin:

```
ldapsearch \
    -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" \
    -w ${ADMIN_PW} \
    -b 'dc=example,dc=com' \
    "(&(uid=tester)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(memberOf=ou=testingGroup,dc=example,dc=com))"
```

I want to enable users to do the above searches themselves (instead of being able to do it only as the admin), as shown below. But they don't (yet) seem to have the permission to search for data pertaining to themselves and I don't know how to enable it correctly. In short, when I run the commands as the *tester* user, I get "32 No such object" as a result instead of the results I get as the *admin* user, but I want the same results. I want these searches to work:

```
ldapsearch \
    -D "uid=tester,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" \
    -w ${USER_PW} \
    -b 'dc=example,dc=com' \
    "(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=uid=tester,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com))"

ldapsearch \
    -D "uid=tester,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" \
    -w ${USER_PW} \
    -b 'dc=example,dc=com' \
    "(&(uid=tester)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(memberOf=ou=testingGroup,dc=example,dc=com))"
```

I suspect that the answer is found [here](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html) but I'm new to OpenLDAP and haven't managed to figure out how to do it. Please, can you help me out?

Comment: The easy way is to enable the `memberOf` overlay, and allow the user access to the `memberOf` attribute in his own entry. Note that enabling it won't affect existing entries so you would have a task of updating those.

Comment: @user207421 This isn't a question about how to enable the overlay because it's already enabled. Hence the mention of "memberOf" in the filter. It's a question about the permission to use it after it's already been enabled., It's about granting non-admin users permission to use the "memberOf" overlay and the "member" attribute of the groupOfNames objectClass.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to give users permission to search for their own memberOf attribute, with the following configuration:

```
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=extern
 al,cn=auth manage by * break
olcAccess: {1}to dn.subtree="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" by sel
 f read by anonymous auth
olcAccess: {2}to dn.children="dc=example,dc=com" attrs=userPassw
 ord,shadowLastChange by self write
```

And with this command:

```
ldapsearch \
    -D "uid=tester,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" \
    -w ${USER_PW} \
    -b 'uid=tester,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com' \
    memberOf
```

So that part is working, whereas I couldn't determine how to configure the *olcAccess* entries further so that users can also search within a directory and be shown the group they're a member of. It seems to have something to do with "[access to attrs=member,entry by dnattr=member](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html)" (perhaps in combination with a [control field](https://linux.die.net/man/5/slapd.access) in the previous entry), but I couldn't find out how it works. I got this far before I had to give up:

```
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=extern
 al,cn=auth manage by * break
olcAccess: {1}to dn.subtree="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" by sel
 f read break by anonymous auth
olcAccess: {2}to dn.subtree="ou=testingGroup,dc=example,dc=com" a
 ttrs=member,entry by dnattr=member read
olcAccess: {3}to dn.children="dc=example,dc=com" attrs=userPassw
 ord,shadowLastChange by self write
```

I find that [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1065022), [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1109214), [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/slapd.access.5.html), [this](https://serverfault.com/a/975575), and [this](https://serverfault.com/a/482269) link are/were helpful for this issue.

Comment: Have a  look at the Zytrax [LDAP for Rocket Scientists](https://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/) pages. Very useful.

Comment: Thank you for trying to direct me to potential solutions. Unfortunately, I've consulted that link twice before and I couldn't get the insight from it that I need to configure the access as needed.